# Definition CSS via JQuery - only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, frontend

My code:

```css
.main-page-wrapper .side-nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:first-child > a {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-page-wrapper">
  <div class="side-nav">
  
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">1-2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="">2-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2-2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="">3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3-2</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

What I need:
change element definitions via CSS to defining this element via JQuery. Anyone help?

Comment: Just use the same selector with JQuery `$('.main-page-wrapper .side-nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:first-child > a').css('fontSize', '40px');`. Note that in a script, the hyphen is replaced with camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

There're so many ways you can do this

Add the style directly to head or body tag

```
$("head").append('<style>.main-page-wrapper .side-nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:first-child > a { font-size:40px; }</style>');
```

OR

```
$("<style>").text(".main-page-wrapper .side-nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:first-child > a { font-size:40px; }").appendTo(document.head);
```

OR

Rebuild style

```
$(".main-page-wrapper .side-nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:first-child > a").attr("style", "font-size:40px");
```

Any of these will do the job.

Comment: useful perfect!

Comment: If it worked for you, please select it as the chosen answer. Merry Christmas